# rotate/spin a body when collide with another

Tags: java, android, box2d, andengine, game-physics

I'm implementing a physics game powered by AndEngine with box2d.
suppose there is an object falling from above vertically.
the ball collide with another object, and change its direction

now, after the collision, the ball should spin/rotate in the air, right?

so, I wanted to know if I need to do the calculation by myself (and how?) using setAngularVelocity function
or box2d can do it automatically.

I hope I expressed myself correctly 
thanks for the help
sock.socket

Answer (score 3):

No... you dont need to do any calculations... when you create your physics connector for your body like this..

```
   public PhysicsConnector(final IShape pShape, final Body pBody, final boolean pUdatePosition, final boolean pUpdateRotation) {
```

if you set the pUpdateRotation true... you can see your body rotating.. and if dont want to see..put it to false... but this  will only disable the updating of the sprite on the screen. It still keeps the Body in the Physics.. so the body will still be rotating.. but the rotation is  not visible...

Comment: OK, now I've noticed I'm using this constructor:
`public PhysicsConnector(final Shape pShape, final Body pBody) {
  this(pShape, pBody, true, true, true, true);
 }`

but I don't see changes in the rotation. only position is get updated..

Comment: sure, what I mean is that I'm using this constructor where all the   
parameter are "ture", but still - no rotation when objects collides with each other... (only position get updates)

Comment: Did you scale your sprite.. or made any chnages to it?

Comment: no.
this is the fixture:
`private static final FixtureDef FIXTURE_DEF = PhysicsFactory.createFixtureDef(1, 1.1f, 0.3f);`

I should mention that both of the bodies are *circles*.

Comment: and both of the circle bodies are "DynamicBody"

Comment: ok, I found a solution:
mPhysicsWorld.registerPhysicsConnector(new PhysicsConnector(ballSprite, ballBody, true, true, false, false));

I didn't understand it completely but it works (changed it to: "true, true, false, false")

Comment: yes... this is the order of the parameters for the physicsconnector method **final Shape pShape, final Body pBody, final boolean pUdatePosition, final boolean pUpdateRotation, final boolean pUpdateLinearVelocity, final boolean pUpdateAngularVelocity**

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else reading this, another reason your sprite might not be rotating is if the friction of the fixture/fixtures is set to 0. (think sliding on ice).

Comment: Did you answer the question?